# How can I store these numbers in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Lets say you had an array like this

```
{ 1 2 5 7 2 3 7 4 2 1 }
```

And you wanted to store that the difference between the first half of the array and the second half is at positions 2 and 4.

The trick is, I need to use those stored numbers later in other code, so what I can't figure out is how I would store these numbers.

I have this method

```
int * getPositions(int *array, int size){
    int * c[(size/2)];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size /2; i++) {
        if (*(array + i) != *(array + (size - 1) - i)) {
            c[counter]= (int *) i;
            counter++;
        }
    }return (int *) c;
 }
```

but it seems to be storing `-1774298560` into every location. I know that cause when I try to print it

```
int c = (int) getPositions(array, size_of_array);

for(int i = 0; i < ((size_of_array/2)); i++){
    printf("%d\t", c);
}
```

all it prints out is

```
-1774298560 -1774298560 -1774298560 -1774298560 -1774298560
```

PS: I have `array` and `size_of_array` initialized somewhere else.

PS: I have taken the comments into consideration and changed the code to the following

```
int * getPositions(int *array, int size){
    int * c = (int *) malloc((size_t) (size/2));
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size /2; i++) {
        if (*(array + i) != *(array + (size - 1) - i)) {
            c[counter]= i;
            counter++;
        }
}
```

Comment: `c` is an array of pointers.  If you want to return a pointer, you should not be returning `c` (since it's not a pointer).

Comment: And if getPositions returns a pointer, why are you casting it to int and assigning it to an int?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what if I want to return an int array from this method?

Comment: Don't use casts unless you know what you are doing... Actually even i you think you know, you probably should abstain.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I use intelliJ and it told me to put in the casts.

Comment: Also, `c` is a local variable. In other words, the array of pointers is on the stack. As soon as the function returns, `c` goes poof, it no longer exists.

Comment: You have multiple things you are doing wrong, and the compiler probably complains about them which is why you are using so much casting. Casting is almost *never* the proper solution to fix a compiler warning or error, it just tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing so shut up", and if you really don't know what you're doing then bad things happen and you end up with *undefined behaviors*-

Comment: @chqrlie I thought it was pointless having the casts there but I use intelliJ and it insisted that I use them.

Comment: IntelliJ insisted you have mistakes in your code, and offered ill advice on how to silence it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm kinda new to C hence why I asked for help. The compiler doesn't give me any errors but I do understand that the extra casting is quite stupid in this case.

Comment: So my questions stands, if I wanted the method to return a simple int array, what do I have to do?

Comment: The main options are to pass in an integer buffer/array into the function as a parameter and fill that in inside the function. Or the function can allocate dynamic memory for an integer array, fill that in and then return it.

Comment: Your edited code wasn't supposed to compile at all...

Comment: @Aftnix I have changed it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function should return a simple `int` array, you need to declare a pointer-to-int, and then call `malloc` to reserve space for the array. Then fill in the array, and return the pointer. The calling function will need to `free` the memory at some point.

```
int *getPositions(int *array, int size)
{
    int *c = malloc( (size/2) * sizeof(int) );
    if ( c == NULL )
        return NULL;

    // put stuff in the array using array syntax, e.g. 
    c[0] = array[0];

    return c;
}
```

Call the function like this

```
int *c = getPositions( array, size );

if ( c != NULL ) 
    for( int i = 0; i < (size/2)); i++ )
        printf( "%d\t", c[i] );

free( c );
```

Notes:

- Yes, error checking in C is a pain, but you must do it, or your
  program will randomly crash.
- You are allowed to use array syntax with a pointer, just be sure you don't read or write past the end of the memory that the pointer references.
- It's legal to pass a `NULL` pointer to `free`.

Comment: I'd rather check for `NULL`, warn about allocation failure and exit accordingly. This means that everything afterwards can rely on `c` being valid and so be placed outside the `if (c != NULL)`.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you. This explains a lot and it actually works now! Thanks again!!! :D

Comment: @black I agree for command line apps: all errors are fatal and result in immediate termination. With GUI based apps, the requirements are a little different: errors need to be handled gracefully, the app can't just terminate abruptly.

Answer (score 2):

Another option.

```
int * getPositions(int *array, int size);
int main() {
    int array[] = { 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 3, 7, 4, 2, 1 };

    int size_of_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    int *ptr = getPositions(array, size_of_array);

    for(int i = 0; ptr[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        printf("%d\t", *(ptr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
int * getPositions(int *array, int size) {
    int temp[size/2];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2 ; i++) {
        if (array[i] != array[(size - 1) - i]) {
            temp[counter++] = i;
        }
    }
    int *c = malloc(counter * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        c[i] = temp[i];
    }

    return  c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My compiler going mad actually...which compiler you're using? Any modern static analyzer should have warned you

```
aftnix@dev:~⟫ gcc -std=c11 -Wall st.c 
st.c: In function ‘getPositions’:
st.c:8:25: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
             c[counter]= (int *) i;
                         ^
st.c:11:6: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     }return (int *) c;
      ^
st.c: In function ‘main’:
st.c:16:13: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
     int c = (int) getPositions(array, 10);
```

So compiler is showing all the problems of the code. And your edited code doesn't even compile :

```
aftnix@dev:~⟫ gcc -std=c11 -Wall st.c 
st.c:4:4: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token
 int[] getPositions(int *array, int size){
    ^
st.c: In function ‘main’:
st.c:17:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getPositions’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int c = (int) getPositions(array, 10);
```

Couple of things you have to take into consideration.

1. If you need to return a storage address, never try to return a local variable. As local variables are allocated in the Stack. Stack frames have the same lifetime of the function. Use `malloc` and co to allocate memory at the Heap. Understanding how the Runtime data structures are allocated and used is a very essential for a `C` programmer as C doesn't have fancy magical stuff under the hood. C is pretty much bare metal.

[Stack Vs Heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)

2. When passing arrays/pointers around, you should first think about your design first. Do you want to change your original array "in place"? or you want a different copy of "transformed" array. Usually you should try to avoid changing a memory "in place" as there might be other users to that. But if don't have such worries, you can then design your function as a "input->output" basis. That means you will not be returning `void`, and will return the transformed array itself.